# Leaving space to element even with display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styles

Just a simple question:
I have a notification message that can be visible or invisible in a webpage (with jQuery `show()` or `hide()`), always in the same place. The problem I am facing is when it appears, it drags down all the contents below it, just it height.

How can I smartly deal with this situation to leave a (blank or not) area so the UI does not change its height when this component disappears/appears?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `show()` and `hide()`, you can just add css property `opacity:0` and `opacity:1` with jquery. This would leave a blank space even the element is not shown.

Comment: Something like this: `$("yourselectorhere")[0].style.opacity = 0;`   Or set it to 1

Comment: Thanks! Finally used https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/ function to make it shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css property `visibility: hidden;` and `visibility: visible;`. This would leave a blank space and UI does not change its height.